# How to remove cancel button from order view page in admin for particular admin user in Magento 2.3.2

Tags: admin, orders

I need to remove Order cancel button from order view page in admin side, as well from mass action in magento 2.3.2 for particular user.

Answer (score 2):

Create file in `adminhtml` `app\code\Ketan\Buttons\etc\adminhtml\di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button\Toolbar">
        <plugin name="RemoveCancelButton" type="Ketan\Buttons\Plugin\Widget\Context" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Create Plugin file `app\code\Ketan\Buttons\Plugin\Widget\Context.php`

```
<?php

namespace Ketan\Buttons\Plugin\Widget;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button\ButtonList;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button\Toolbar as ToolbarContext;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock;

class Context
{
    protected $coreRegistry;
    protected $authSession;
    public function __construct(
        Registry $coreRegistry,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession,
    ) {
        $this->coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        $this->authSession = $authSession;
    }

    /**
     * @param ToolbarContext $toolbar
     * @param AbstractBlock $context
     * @param ButtonList $buttonList
     * @return array
     */
    public function beforePushButtons(
        ToolbarContext $toolbar,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button\ButtonList $buttonList
    ) {
        if (!$context instanceof \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View) {
            return [$context, $buttonList];
        }
        $user = $this->authSession->getUser();
        $userName = $user->getUsername();
        if($userName=='admin' || $userName=='superadmin'){
            $buttonList->remove('order_cancel');
        }

        return [$context, $buttonList];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create plugin to remove cancel button from order view page.

```
namespace NameSpace\OrderManagement\Plugin\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order;

use NameSpace\OrderManagement\Helper\Data;
use Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View;
use Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface;
```

class ViewPlugin
{

```
/**
 * @var Data
 */
protected $helper;

public function __construct(Data $helper)
{
    $this->helper = $helper;
}//end __construct()

public function beforeSetLayout(View $view, LayoutInterface $layout)
{
    if ($this->helper->isAllowedtoDisplayCancelButton()) {
        $view->removeButton('order_cancel');
    }
}//end beforeSetLayout()
```

}//end class

create di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View">
    <plugin name="removeBackButton" type="NameSpace\OrderManagement\Plugin\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\ViewPlugin"/>
</type>
```

create Helper file and add below function

```
public function isAllowedtoDisplayCancelButton()
{
    return !$this->authorization->isAllowed('Magento_Backend::all') &&
    $this->authorization->isAllowed('Magento_Sales::cancel');
}//end isCustomerSupportAgent()
```

and add Magento_Sales::cancel resource in your acl.xml

Hope it will work for you please accept my answer.